# How to plot a line between points taken from different rows of 2D array in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, multidimensional-array

I have a 2D array of size 2xN call it A and another 1xN call it B. I want to draw a  vertical line between elements of the first row and second row (i.e., draw a line between A[0,0] and A[1,0] and the line is on the horizontal axis with value B[0] or say A[0,4] and A[1,4] with horizontal axis value of B[4], etc.) with their value on the horizontal axis being B[corresponding column].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll preface by saying I'm not 100% sure what you are asking for. With what I believe you are asking however, this does the trick.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from random import randint

A = []
B = []
n = randint(1,10)

for i in range(n):
    A.append([randint(1,10),randint(1,10)])
    B.append(randint(1,10))

for i in range(n):
    plt.plot(B[i], A[i][0], "ro")
    plt.plot(B[i], A[i][1], "ro")
    plt.plot((B[i], B[i]), (A[i][0], A[i][1]), "c-")

plt.show()
```

[image: sample graph]

Comment: Not exactly what I wanted but I figured it out the rest with your answer, thanks.

Comment: Glad I could help :)